How to load ALL Elementor styles on a plugin's page
One of my plugins creates a page which loads the footer and header with get_footer() and get_header() following the wp standard. Now the design is messed up cause global Elementor styles are undefined.
I ask Elementor support about this. They are saying get_header() might not be enough to load global styles. And because the page is created by a plugin they dont want to help further. They don't even give a hint to resources.
For testing I created a new page in the wordpress editor and copied the source (doctype to body tag and closing body/html tag) from that page to the plugin's template. And then everyhing looks fine.
I made a long research for this but can't find any clear solution.
But copying html source from one page to another isn't the best approach. I hope anybody knows what I still need to add beside get_header() and get_footer() to run all the elementor stuff? Like a elementor basic skeleton.
